# spring boot rest api mongodb update entity

Tags: spring, mongodb, rest

I've a problem with updating my entity. I've rest api where I use request mapping "/people/{id}" with PUT method. If I make a request I get an error like this -> "Write failed with error code 11000 and error message 'E11000 duplicate key error collection:..."

Where is the problem ? I use mongo database. Code below:

```
@PutMapping("/people/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Person> updatePerson(@PathVariable String id, 
@Valid @RequestBody Person person) {
Optional<Person> personToUpdate = 
Optional.ofNullable(this.personRepository.findOne(id));
if(!personToUpdate.isPresent()) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
if(personToUpdate.get().getName() != null) {
    personToUpdate.get().setName(person.getName());

}
if(personToUpdate.get().getSurname() != null) {
    personToUpdate.get().setSurname(person.getSurname());

}
if(personToUpdate.get().getBirthDate() != null) {
    personToUpdate.get().setBirthDate(person.getBirthDate());
}
if(personToUpdate.get().getDateOfDeath() != null) {
    personToUpdate.get().setDateOfDeath(person.getDateOfDeath());
}
if(personToUpdate.get().getGraveId() != null) {
    personToUpdate.get().setGraveId(person.getGraveId());
}

Person updatedPerson = this.personRepository.insert(personToUpdate.get());

return new ResponseEntity<>(updatedPerson, HttpStatus.OK);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is the culprit

```
Person updatedPerson = this.personRepository.insert(personToUpdate.get();
```

You are using insert instead of save.  You should be doing

```
Person updatedPerson = this.personRepository.save(personToUpdate.get();
```

There is difference between `insert` and `save`. In simple terms.
`save` is equivalent to insert or update.
`insert` is just insert.

Hence if you use insert, it tries to insert a new record(This is okay, if you don't specify the id),  but you are specifying id  which results in duplicate key.

Comment: Ok, but if do not provide all required fields it gives me NULL in json, why and how to change it ?

Comment: which json are you talking about

Comment: Ok, there was not question. Do you think it's good idea to check fields before null like I wrote above ? Is there any faster and better looking idea without this too many if's ?

Comment: Well, that depends. If you trust your new object which is coming from PUT to have all the required fields, then you can just take the id field from the database object and just add that to your new object and save. But if the object froming from PUT doesn't have all the fields or Object in database have some fields null, then you have to do what you are doing now.

Comment: Ok, in this way I've done above is there any better idea to replace this too many if's ?

Comment: No, I don't think so except that it is a better idea to move this whole logic from controller to a service class.. Do accept the answer. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying that there's already a record with the same person. 
In other words, you already have a person with the input attributes. Try to change your request body.